# Cancelar una accion

Tags: html, jquery

estoy diseñando una tabla html con Jquery la cual solo edita los registros o simplemente cancela al momento de editar, la cual aquí empieza mi problema. Simplemente deseo es que al presionar el botón cancelar vuelvan los datos a como estaban antes, por ejemplo:

En mi tabla borre por accidente el apellido "Sanchez". Entonces solo presiono el boton cancelar y que me devuelva en mi registro el apellido "Sanchez" como si no hubiera sido editado.

En mi botón "Cancelar" solo ejecuta en "true" el disabled de los input, nada mas, pues no tengo idea de como volver los datos que fueron editados por accidente.

Les enseño mi código para que me puedan ayudar:

```js
$("#Editar1").click(function(){   
      $("#nombre1").prop("disabled", false);
       $("#apellido1").prop("disabled", false);
     });
       
$("#Cancelar1").click(function(){   
      $("#nombre1").prop("disabled", true);
       $("#apellido1").prop("disabled", true);
     });
       
       
       $("#Editar2").click(function(){   
      $("#nombre2").prop("disabled", false);
       $("#apellido2").prop("disabled", false);
     });
       
$("#Cancelar2").click(function(){   
      $("#nombre2").prop("disabled", true);
       $("#apellido2").prop("disabled", true);
     });
       
       
       $("#Editar3").click(function(){   
      $("#nombre3").prop("disabled", false);
       $("#apellido3").prop("disabled", false);
     });
       
$("#Cancelar3").click(function(){   
      $("#nombre3").prop("disabled", true);
       $("#apellido3").prop("disabled", true);
     });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border=1 >
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Id</th><th>Col 2</th><th>Col 3</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
 <tbody>
   <tr>
     <td>1</td>
     <td><input id="nombre1" disabled value="Juan"></td>
     <td><input id="apellido1" disabled value="sanchez"></td>
     <td><button id="Editar1">Editar</button></td>
     <td><button id="Cancelar1">Cancelar</button></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>2</td><td><input id="nombre2" disabled value="Joanna"></td><td><input id="apellido2" disabled value="herrera"></td>
     <td><button id="Editar2">Editar</button></td>
     <td><button id="Cancelar2">Cancelar</button></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>3</td><td><input id="nombre3" disabled value="Marcos"></td><td><input id="apellido3"  disabled value="lopez"></td>
     <td><button id="Editar3">Editar</button></td>
     <td><button id="Cancelar3">Cancelar</button></td>
   </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Espero que puedan ayudarme, gracias.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

En primer lugar deberias usar clases en lugar de ID's para no repetir el codigo.  En cuanto a tu pregunta, puedes usar un span que contenga el texto.  Cuando Presionas "Editar" escondes el span y muestras el input.  Si presionas Cancelar, simplemente escondes el input y muestras el span original.  Tambien necesitarias un boton "Guardar", para cambiar el texto del span y ocultar el input.

Algo asi:

```js
$(".editar").click(function(){
    var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    tr.find('input').show();
    tr.find('span').hide();
    $(this).hide();
    tr.find('.guardar').show();    
});
       
$(".cancelar").click(function(){
    var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    tr.find('span').show();
    tr.find('input').hide();
    tr.find('.guardar').hide();
    tr.find('.editar').show();
});

$(".guardar").click(function(){
    var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    var spans = tr.find('span');
    $.each(spans, function(i, span) {
 var input = $(this).siblings('input');
        $(this).html(input.val());
    });
    spans.show();
    tr.find('input').hide();
    $(this).hide();
    tr.find('.editar').show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border=1 >
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Id</th><th>Col 2</th><th>Col 3</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
 <tbody>
   <tr>
     <td>1</td>
     <td><span>Juan</span><input style="display:none;" value="Juan"></td>
     <td><span>sanchez</span><input style="display:none;" value="sanchez"></td>
     <td><button class="editar">Editar</button><button style="display:none;" class="guardar">Guardar</button></td>
     <td><button class="cancelar">Cancelar</button></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>2</td><td><span>Joanna</span><input style="display:none;" value="Joanna"></td><td><span>herrera</span><input style="display:none;" value="herrera"></td>
     <td><button class="editar">Editar</button><button style="display:none;" class="guardar">Guardar</button></td>
     <td><button class="cancelar">Cancelar</button></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>3</td><td><span>Marcos</span><input style="display:none;" value="Marcos"></td><td><span>lopez<input style="display:none;" value="lopez"></td>
     <td><button class="editar">Editar</button><button style="display:none;" class="guardar">Guardar</button></td>
     <td><button class="cancelar">Cancelar</button></td>
   </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: al editar sin querer borre el campo y al pulsar el boton cancelar no se restablece al valor anterior, al pulsar nuevamente el boton editar aparece el campo en blanco

Answer (score 6):

He cambiado varias cosas en el html y el JQuery  que van por pasar de usar ids 
 que usabas para asignar la función click a funciones a asignadas por el `class`como primer paso. De ahí use la función [.data()](https://api.jquery.com/data/) para guardar el valor antes de ser modificado para que si cancela la operación  se regrese al original , en este ejemplo use `value` como una key para guardar el valor. Lo demás esta explicado en el código. Espero te sirva.

```js
// forma  de como asignar la funcion click a elementos con
// class edit o cancel

$(".edit").click(function() {
  //me ubico en el tr padre
  var tr = $(this).parent().parent();
  // obtengo los objetos html apellido y nombre y los guardo
  var nombre = tr.find("#nombre");
  var apellido = tr.find("#apellido");

  //condicional  de acuerdo si estas editando o guardando
  if ($(this).text() == "Editar") {

    //guardo los objetos con .data() antes de editarlos
    nombre.data("value", nombre.val());
    apellido.data("value", apellido.val());

    //busco en el bloque de html del tr al nombre y lo vuelvo editable
    nombre.prop("disabled", false);
    //busco en el bloque de html del tr al apellido y lo vuelvo editable
    apellido.prop("disabled", false);
    //cambio el texto de editar por guardar
    $(this).text("Guardar");

  } else {
    nombre.prop("disabled", true);
    apellido.prop("disabled", true);
    $(this).text("Editar");

  }

});

$(".cancel").click(function() {
  //me ubico en el tr padre
  var tr = $(this).parent().parent();

  // si esta editando cambia el texto
  if (tr.find("#edit").text() == "Guardar") {
    tr.find("#edit").text("Editar");

    // obtengo los objetos html apellido y nombre 
    var nombre = tr.find("#nombre");
    var apellido = tr.find("#apellido");

    // como se cancelo regreso al valor anterior con .data()
    nombre.val(nombre.data("value"));
    apellido.val(apellido.data("value"));

    //busco en el bloque de html del tr al nombre y apellido y los vuelvo disabled
    nombre.prop("disabled", true);
    apellido.prop("disabled", true);

  }

});
```

```css
button {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border=1>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>Col 2</th>
      <th>Col 3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td><input id="nombre" disabled value="Juan"></td>
      <td><input id="apellido" disabled value="sanchez"></td>
      <td><button id="edit" class="edit">Editar</button></td>
      <td><button id="cancel" class="cancel">Cancelar</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td><input id="nombre" disabled value="Joanna"></td>
      <td><input id="apellido" disabled value="herrera"></td>
      <td><button id="edit" class="edit">Editar</button></td>
      <td><button id="cancel" class="cancel">Cancelar</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td><input id="nombre" disabled value="Marcos"></td>
      <td><input id="apellido" disabled value="lopez"></td>
      <td><button id="edit" class="edit">Editar</button></td>
      <td><button id="cancel" class="cancel">Cancelar</button></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: No necesitas usar `.data()` para guardar el valor de un elemento `<input>` ya que el DOM cuenta con la propiedad `.defaultValue`.

Answer (score 4):

Debes guardarlos antes de editarlos. Y así ese valor no se perderá. Lo hice solo con los nombres, pero ya entiendes la idea.

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", _ => {

var firstValues = {
 nombre1: document.getElementById("nombre1").value,
 apellido1: document.getElementById("apellido1").value,
 nombre2: document.getElementById("nombre2").value,
 apellido2: document.getElementById("apellido2").value,
 nombre3: document.getElementById("nombre3").value,
 apellido3: document.getElementById("apellido3").value
};

$("#Editar1").click(function(){   
      $("#nombre1").prop("disabled", false);
       $("#apellido1").prop("disabled", false);
     });
       
$("#Cancelar1").click(function(){   
      document.getElementById("nombre1").value = firstValues.nombre1;
      $("#nombre1").prop("disabled", true);
       $("#apellido1").prop("disabled", true);
     });
       
       
       $("#Editar2").click(function(){   
      $("#nombre2").prop("disabled", false);
       $("#apellido2").prop("disabled", false);
     });
       
$("#Cancelar2").click(function(){
document.getElementById("nombre2").value = firstValues.nombre2;
      $("#nombre2").prop("disabled", true);
       $("#apellido2").prop("disabled", true);
     });
       
       
       $("#Editar3").click(function(){   
      $("#nombre3").prop("disabled", false);
       $("#apellido3").prop("disabled", false);
     });
       
$("#Cancelar3").click(function(){   
document.getElementById("nombre3").value = firstValues.nombre3;
      $("#nombre3").prop("disabled", true);
       $("#apellido3").prop("disabled", true);
     });
   });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border=1 >
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Id</th><th>Col 2</th><th>Col 3</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
 <tbody>
   <tr>
     <td>1</td>
     <td><input id="nombre1" disabled value="Juan"></td>
     <td><input id="apellido1" disabled value="sanchez"></td>
     <td><button id="Editar1">Editar</button></td>
     <td><button id="Cancelar1">Cancelar</button></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>2</td><td><input id="nombre2" disabled value="Joanna"></td><td><input id="apellido2" disabled value="herrera"></td>
     <td><button id="Editar2">Editar</button></td>
     <td><button id="Cancelar2">Cancelar</button></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>3</td><td><input id="nombre3" disabled value="Marcos"></td><td><input id="apellido3"  disabled value="lopez"></td>
     <td><button id="Editar3">Editar</button></td>
     <td><button id="Cancelar3">Cancelar</button></td>
   </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 4):

Yo te cambiaría una serie de cosas:

1. para empezar todos los botones editar hacen lo mismo, habilitar los `input` que están en la misma fila así que en vez de utilizar una id para cada botón, utilizo un `class` para identificar los botones y asignarles una función a todos los que posean este atributo `class`
2. Lo segundo que haría sería eliminar el botón cancelar
3. Una vez eliminado el botón cancelar utilizo una interfaz de dialogo para cambiar el valor del `input`, de esta forma tengo cierto control sobre lo que se está cambiando
4. lo cuarto que haría sería hacer todo por referencias, ej: si le hago click a un botón editar, voy a la fila del boton (elemento `tr`) y busco por los elementos `input` para habilitarlos o deshabilitarlos

haciendo todo lo anterior te queda un código más limpio fácil de leer y mantenible.

PD: jQuery tiene la opción de manejar eventos sobre objetos con un elemento HTML como objetivo de esta forma solo utilizas un evento y no un evento por cada elemento que quieras que ejecute la misma acción **$(*selector*).on(*evento*,*objetivo*, *funcion a llamar*)** ejemplo:

```
$('#tabla1').on('click','tr', function(){...});
```

el código editado sería el siguiente:

```js
// evento que se ejecuta al hacer click sobre el boton editar
$('.btnEditar').on('click', function(){
  // obtengo todos los input de la fila (tr) donde esta el boton clickeado
  var inputs = $(this).parent().parent().find('input');
  // para cada input de esta fila invierto el valor de la propiedad 'disabbled', de manera que si esta habilitado lo desabilita y viceversa
  $.each(inputs, function(key, value){
    $(value).prop('disabled',!$(value).prop('disabled'))
  })
  
})

// funcion que se ejecuta en el evento click de los input
$('#tabla1').on('click','input',function(){
  // al hacer click en un input me levanta un dialog con un input conteniendo el mismo valor del input clickeado
  var inputValue = prompt('Ingrese Valor', this.value);
  // si el valor es null significa que presiono `cancelar` en caso contrario se guarda el valor ingresado
  if(inputValue !== null){
    this.value = inputValue;
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tabla1" border=1 >
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Id</th><th>Nombre</th><th>Apellido</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
 <tbody>
   <tr>
     <td>1</td>
     <td><input disabled value="Juan"></td>
     <td><input disabled value="sanchez"></td>
     <td><button class="btnEditar">Editar</button></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>2</td>
     <td><input disabled value="Joanna"></td>
     <td><input disabled value="herrera"></td>
     <td><button class="btnEditar">Editar</button></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>3</td>
     <td><input disabled value="Marcos"></td>
     <td><input disabled value="lopez"></td>
     <td><button class="btnEditar">Editar</button></td>
   </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: LPZadkiel estoy probando tu respuesta pero igual que al OP me equivoque y sin querer borre el nombre, como puedo hacer para volver al valor anterior si ahora no tengo el boton para cancelar?

Comment: `prompt` es un método que levanta un cuadro de dialogo que siempre tendrá botones "Ok" y "Cancel", ahora si me preguntas "que pasa si no tengo boton Cancelar?" pues entonces no estas siguiente mi respuesta y decidiste ir por otro camino y no puedo ayudarte si no se como quieres resolver este problema, si me muestras como quieres hacerlo quizás te pueda ayudar

Answer (score 1):

Ya casi lo tienes!!... Los elementos de un `<form>` cuenta con la propiedad `defaultValue`, con esto puede hacer que al presionar el botón `cancelar` vuelvas a colocar los valores por defecto antes de la modificación.

Partiendo de tu codigo te dejo un ejemplo de cómo hacerlo

```js
$("*[id^='Editar']").click( function(){
 $(this).closest("tr").find("input").each(function(){
  this.disabled = false;
 });
});

$("*[id^='Cancelar']").click( function(){
 $(this).closest("tr").find("input").each(function(){
  this.value = this.defaultValue;
  this.disabled = true;
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border=1 >
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Id</th><th>Col 2</th><th>Col 3</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
 <tbody>
   <tr>
     <td>1</td>
     <td><input id="nombre1" disabled value="Juan"></td>
     <td><input id="apellido1" disabled value="sanchez"></td>
     <td><button id="Editar1">Editar</button></td>
     <td><button id="Cancelar1">Cancelar</button></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>2</td><td><input id="nombre2" disabled value="Joanna"></td><td><input id="apellido2" disabled value="herrera"></td>
     <td><button id="Editar2">Editar</button></td>
     <td><button id="Cancelar2">Cancelar</button></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>3</td><td><input id="nombre3" disabled value="Marcos"></td><td><input id="apellido3"  disabled value="lopez"></td>
     <td><button id="Editar3">Editar</button></td>
     <td><button id="Cancelar3">Cancelar</button></td>
   </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```