# ¿Cómo puedo editar la fila de una tabla con jquery? son datos dinámicos, sin BD

Tags: html, jquery

```js
$(document).ready(function(){


 $("#guardar").click(function(){
  var codigo = $("#codigo").val();
  var nombre = $("#nombre").val();
  var cantidad = $("#cantidad").val();
  var costo = $("#costo").val();

  if($("#codigo").val().length < 1) {  
        alert("Por favor ingrese el código del producto");
        return false;  
     }
     if($("#nombre").val().length < 1) {  
        alert("Por favor ingrese el nombre del producto");  
        return false;  
     }
     if($("#cantidad").val().length < 1) {  
        alert("Por favor ingrese la cantidad del producto");  
        return false;  
     }
     if($("#costo").val().length < 1) {  
        alert("Por favor ingrese el costo del producto");  
        return false;  
     }
     $("#formularioProductos")[0].reset();

     swal({
      title: "Producto agregado",
      icon: "success",
     });

  $("#listaProductos").append( '<tr id="producto"><td>' + codigo + '</td>' + '<td>' + nombre + '</td>' + '<td>' + cantidad + '</td>' + '<td>' + costo + '</td><td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" >Eliminar</button><button type="button" class="btn btn-success" >Editar</button></td></tr>');

  $("table").on('click', ".btn-danger", eliminarRegistro);
  function eliminarRegistro(){
   $(this).parent().parent().remove();
   swal({
    title:"Producto eliminado",
    icon: "error",
   });
  }

 })
 
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Productos</title>
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
     <h2>Productos</h2>
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
     Agregar nuevo
  </button><br><br>
     <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
          <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Ingrese los datos del producto</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <form id="formularioProductos">
     <div class="form-group">
         <label>Código</label>
         <input type="text" class="form-control" id="codigo" placeholder="Código del producto">
       </div>
       <div class="form-group">
         <label>Nombre</label>
         <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nombre" placeholder="Nombre del producto">
       </div>
       <div class="form-group">
         <label>Cantidad</label>
         <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cantidad" placeholder="Cantidad de productos">
       </div>
       <div class="form-group">
         <label>Costo</label>
         <input type="text" class="form-control" id="costo" placeholder="Costo del producto">
       </div>
    </form>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" id="guardar" data-dismiss="modal">Guardar</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
      
     <table class="table table-bordered" >
      <thead>
       <tr>
        <th>Código</th>
        <th>Nombre</th>
        <th>Cantidad</th>
        <th>Costo</th>
        <th>Operaciones</th>
       </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody id="listaProductos">
       
      </tbody>
      
  </table>
    </div>
 
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

```
Cita en bloque
```

Comment: quires que lo edite para siempres o solo quieres de muestra?

Comment: Contenste una pregunta similar aqui: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/152388/cancelar-una-accion/152389#152389

Comment: Que lo edite para siempre

Comment: Hola Harim, hay varias maneras de hacer lo que necesitas. Por ejemplo con "knockoutjs" a mi me parece mas facil. Puedes revisar el siguiente link. http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/03/guard-your-model-accept-or-cancel-edits.html espero que te sirva. Saludos