# Editar tabla con Modal

Tags: php, ajax, modal

Buenas tengo que modificar un sistema en cual tengo que poder editar una tabla el código es el siguiente quiero que se habrá un modal con la información de la tabla escogida  y poder editarla con ajax para no recargar la pagina, he visto un par de tutoriales y no consigo hacer que los datos se presenten en el modal.[image: <code>introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí</code>]

```
<?php
require "Conexion.php";
require "Config.php";
try {
$con = new Conexion();
$conn = $con-> conectar();

if(isset($_POST['Codigo'])){
    $query = "SELECT * FROM descuentos WHERE Total > pagado AND Codigo = '".$_POST['Codigo']."' ORDER BY Concepto ASC, Numero ASC;";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute();
    foreach ($stmt as $row) {
        echo "<tr>";
        $query2 = "SELECT Descripcion FROM tipo_descuentos WHERE Codigo = '".$row['Concepto']."';";
        $stmt2 = $conn->prepare($query2);
        $stmt2->execute();
        if($row2 = $stmt2->fetch()){
            echo "<td>".$row2['Descripcion']."</td>";
        }else{
            echo "<td>".$row['Concepto']."</td>";
        }
        echo "<td>".$row['Numero']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['Cuotas']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['CuotaActual']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['Monto']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['Total']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['Abono']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['Glosa']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['FechaIngreso']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['FechaInicio']."</td>";

        echo "<td><a onclick='EliminarDescuento(this);' id='".$row['Id']."' >Eliminar</a></td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
}else{
    echo 0;
}

}catch(PDOException $e){
    echo "ERROR: ". $e->getMessage();
}
$conn=null;
?>
```

Comment: Lo que quieres es editar la fila?

Comment: Claro editar los datos de cada descuento que halla , es la típica tabla con crud ya esta el eliminar ahora quiero el poder editar los registros

Comment: Conteste una pregunta similar aqui: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/152388/cancelar-una-accion/152389#152389