# ¿Cómo actualizar los datos de una tabla creada desde mi js?

Tags: javascript, html, tabla-dinámica

tengo el siguiente inconveniente:

Primero he creado una tabla desde mi js la misma que almacena diferentes items correspondientes a datos de productos, lo que necesito es tomar cualquier item y editarlo, sin embargo, los valores de la tabla no se actualizar.

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que dichas modificaciones se muestren en mi html?

El código es el siguiente:

html:

```
  <tbody id="tabla_producto"> </tbody>
```

js:

```
  var elemento = document.createElement("TR");
    var boton_eliminar = document.createElement("BUTTON");
    var boton_editar = document.createElement("BUTTON");
    boton_eliminar.setAttribute("id", "botonEliminar");
    fila="<tr>" +"<td>"+producto.Cantidad+"</td>" + "<td>"+producto.Descripcion+"</td>" +
    "<td>"+producto.PrecioUnitario+"</td>" +
    "<td>"+tarifaProducto+"</td>" +
    "<td>"+producto.Descuento+"</td>" + 
    "<td>"+valorTotal+"</td>" +
    "<td>"+icePorProd+"</td>" +
    "</tr>";

    $('#myModalCreate').modal('hide');
    elemento.innerHTML=fila;
    document.getElementById("tabla_proucto").appendChild(elemento);
    boton_eliminar.innerText = 'Eliminar';
    boton_editar.innerText = 'Editar';
    document.getElementById("tabla_proucto").appendChild(boton_eliminar);
    document.getElementById("tabla_proucto").appendChild(boton_editar);
   filas.push(fila)
```

js para editar:

```
   filaEdit ="<tr>" +"<td>"+cantidadedit+"</td>" + "<td>"+det.descripcion+"</td>" +
    "<td>"+det.precioUnitario+"</td>" +
    "<td>"+tarifasEdit+"</td>" +
    "<td>"+producto.Descuento+"</td>" + 
    "<td>"+det.precioTotalSinImpuesto+"</td>" +
    "<td>"+CodPorICEedit+"</td>" +
    "</tr>";
    elemeElimi = detalleList.splice(posicionDetalleList, 1);

        fila = filaEdit
```

para efectos de cálculos no existe problema.

Gracias.

Comment: Quizas te interese esta respuesta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/152388/cancelar-una-accion/152389#152389

Comment: quieres modificar lo que esta en la pantalla ? o quieres modificar la fuente de donde vienen los datos ?

Comment: Sí, lo que sale en pantalla. Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

podrías poner un id a los campos de la tabla a cambiar tal que

```
"<td id='descuento'>"+producto.Descuento+"</td>"
```

y con una función actualizar en javascript a la que llamar cada vez que tengas que cambiar los datos, y en ella para cambiar el contenido de la tabla lo puedes hacer con el siguiente código:

```
document.getElementById("descuento").innerHTML = "200";
```